# Can this series diverge?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Suppose we have a series $\sum x_n$ that is known to be convergent. Further, $(y_n)$ is a bounded sequence. Can $\sum x_ny_n$ diverge? If so, provide an example. If not, justify.

I have been thinking about this problem for a couple of hours so far.

Since $(y_n)$ is bounded, we know there exists an $M$ such that $|y_n|\leq M$ for all $n$. Further, $|x_ny_n| \leq |x_n|M$. I haven't concluded anything else.

I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $x_n = (-1)^n\frac 1n$ and $y_n = (-1)^n$.

Remark: If $\sum x_n$ is absolute convergent, then

$$\sum |x_n y_n| \le M \sum |x_n|. $$

This shows that $\sum x_n y_n$ is also absolute convergent. Thus $\sum x_n y_n $ converges.

Comment: How about a series which is absolutely convergent? This is what I assumed out of the OP.

Comment: @AlfredYerger Why would you assume that when it's nowhere in the question?

Comment: @AlfredYerger : Please see the edit.

Comment: Well I assumed it because the series listed in this post is conditionally convergent. I wasn't sure if "convergent" meant "at least conditionally convergent" or if "convergent" meant "more than conditionally convergent."